# How to display dates in two html tables side by side according to month?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display status of employee for each date in a month in the given application.
i have divided data in two tables.
[image: Snapshot of application]

Now, if you can see , My tables are displaying dates correctly.

But i want to start new table for each month. i.e. whenever 1st date of new month begins, i want to start the procedure of rendering dates for the month again.

So i will be able to distinguish them by their months.

I hope i have explained the problem correctly.
Please provide guidance on this .
Thanks in advance.
My code for the given problem :

```
<?php       
    $name=$_SESSION['sess_username'];
    $dateofattendance=$_SESSION['sess_date'];
    $time="00-00-00";
    $status="absent";
    $counter=0;
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', '', '', 'test');
    $sql="SELECT dateofattendance,timeofattendance, status,timeofdeparture FROM attendance Where emp='$name' ORDER BY dateofattendance ASC ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);           
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)         
        {
            echo "<table class='main'><tbody><tr><td >";
            // create the opening table
            echo "<div align='left'><table class='sep1'style='float:left;'; border='black' cellpadding='5' ><thead> <tr><th> Date </th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead>tbody>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                  // create the row
                  echo "<tr><td>" . $row["dateofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofattendance"]. "</td><td>" . $row["timeofdeparture"]. "</td>";
                  if($row["status"]=='present')
                      {
                          echo "<td ><span class='label label-success'>". $row["status"]."</span></td>";
                      }
                  else
                      {
                          echo "<td><span class='label label-danger'>". $row["status"]."</span></td>"; 
                     }"
                </tr>";
            $counter++;  

           // when the counter is 15, close this table and open another
           if($counter == 15)
           {
               echo "</td><td>"; // move to the next cell in our wrap table
               echo "</tbody></table></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
               echo "<table class='sep2'style='float:left;'border='black'cellpadding='5'><thead> <tr><th> Date </th><th>IN</th><th>OUT</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>";  
           } 

         }
// close the last table
echo "</tbody></table>";

// close our wrapper table
echo "</td></tr></tbody></table>";
}

        $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a counter and creating a new table when it hits 15, you want to have a variable that stores the month number of the last row rendered, and check if the month number of the next row to be rendered matches. If it doesn't match, generate a new table.

The following code is produces the results you want. I've tested it with a database table with identical structure (table named "test_employees").

Note, the code outputs valid HTML and I re-formatted the echo statements and added newline chars to make the both the PHP and HTML source code more readable.

This code could be cleaned up considerably, so it's by no means good production code, but again, it demonstrates the logic you are after.

One item to note, the code only works within a given year. Additional code would be required if you wanted to display tables across multiple years.

If this helps you, please mark my answer.

I can also spend more time to refactor this code if you want. Let me know and I'll reply faster the next time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>table test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $name=$_SESSION['sess_username'];
    $dateofattendance=$_SESSION['sess_date'];
    $time="00-00-00";
    $status="absent";
    $counter=0;
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', '', '', 'test_employees');
    $sql="SELECT dateofattendance,timeofattendance, status,timeofdeparture FROM attendance Where emp='$name' ORDER BY dateofattendance ASC ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0)         
    {
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>IN</th>";
        echo "<th>OUT</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

        $first_iteration = 1;
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $last_month_num = split('-', $row["dateofattendance"])[1];

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $current_month_num = split('-', $row["dateofattendance"])[1];

            if ($first_iteration == 1) { // do nothing the first time around
                $first_iteration = 0;
            }
            else if ($current_month_num == $last_month_num) { // only close row in current table
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            else { // close table and start new table
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
                echo "<table border='1'>";
                echo "<thead>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Date</th>";
                echo "<th>IN</th>";
                echo "<th>OUT</th>";
                echo "<th>Status</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</thead>";
                echo "<tbody>";
            }

            echo "<tr>" . "\n";

            echo "<td>" . "\n" . $row["name"] . $row["dateofattendance"] . "\n" . "</td>" . "\n";
            echo "<td>" . "\n" . $row["timeofattendance"] . "\n" . "</td>" . "\n";
            echo "<td>" . "\n" . $row["timeofdeparture"] . "\n" . "</td>" . "\n";

            if($row["status"]=='present')
            {
                echo "<td><span class='label label-success'>". $row["status"]."</span></td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td><span class='label label-danger'>". $row["status"]."</span></td>";
            }

            $counter++;

            $last_month_num = split('-', $row["dateofattendance"])[1];
        }

        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }


    $conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you suggest edits in the code, i got the point,but somehow i am not able to implement it in the code ,sorry for the trouble